# Extending Exception class and logging / emailing

Tags: php, exception

I am trying to extend the exception class, in order to log and email when specify error codes are passed - I would like all the errors thrown to be of the custom exception type for diagnosis - The problem I am running into is how do I tackle when either the email or the logger class fails for any reason

I am thinking I would need to revert to the default Exception in the case of the email or logger class, while for everything else the custom Exception will be used

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem I am running into is how do I tackle when either the email or the logger class fails for any reason

wrap the mail/log attempt in a try-catch block.

```
try{
    myExceptionClass::logException( $customException );
    myExceptionClass::emailNotification( $adminEmail );
}catch( Exception $e ){
    exit( "dangit" );
}
```

Ideally, your error-handling will never allow this to actually happen, so you should be able to consider it an "edge case."  I assume you are still allowing the server to log your PHP errors as well, so you still have something to use to find such a problem.

Comment: Yes I tried that but the problem is that I am trying to use the same filewriter and emailing class from within the Error handler - As you can imagine in the event of an exception in any one of these classes it's a recursive call - Is the best way to have the emailing and logging for the exception handler separate from the one used by the rest of the application?

Comment: right - obviously, if there's a problem with your error handler, you don't want to try and use it _again_.  You would need to implement different (probably much simpler) logic in your `catch{}` block.  This is what I meant by "hopefully it's an edge case" - you don't want things going wrong like this regularly.  Your `catch` would need to be simpler/more robust than your normal error handling.

Comment: ...You might also use `set_exception_handler()` as a fallback to catch any problems that slip past everything else.  During development, mine prints helpful error messages and a stack trace.  When the site is live, it simply redirects the user to an error page.  (It's easy to see when this has happened by checking Apache's logs.)  For the user, it's better than seeing a "broken" page - but honestly, I don't think any user has ever had a chance to see one :)

Comment: @digital_paki did you get this figured out?